# CSS mouseenter shows hidden overlay - Issue when hovering over text overlay disappears

Tags: css

I have written some css which displays an overlay on my image when it is hovered over, the image also has a heading centered in the middle. The heading has `z-index: 999` making sure that it infront of the overlay.

The issue I am having is when I hover of the image the overlay is shown, then when my mouse goes over the text which is infront of the overlay the overlay disappears.

This is the page I am refering to - https://jtracks.org.uk/jtrack/1/module/1

Here is my html code

```
<div class="module" style="background-image: url({{ url('') }}/storage/{{ $lesson_plan->thumbnail }})">
  <h2 class="lesson-thumbnail-number">LESSON {{ $lesson_plan->lesson_number }}</h2>
  <div class="thumbnail-overlay"></div>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS

```
.module {
    margin: 0 10px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    height: 240px;
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-right: 40px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;;
}

.thumbnail-overlay {
    width: 100%;
    height: 240px;
    z-index: 2;  
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; 
    margin-left: -40px;
}

.thumbnail-overlay:hover{ 
  background-color: rgba(0, 150, 107, 0.7);
}
```

NOTE - if you visit the website you will notice when you hover over the image a description appears over the image as well, this was left out to make my question more simplistic. This has the same issue as the title so I am presuming the fix will sort both problems.

Comment: you want to first-time hover then show overlay and not hide next time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
.thumbnail-overlay:hover{ 
  background-color: rgba(0, 150, 107, 0.7);
}
```

to:

```
.module:hover .thumbnail-overlay { 
   background-color: rgba(0, 150, 107, 0.7);
}
```